# Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",: Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file

Tags: r, raster

I have this instruction in my script:

```
wc25 <- stack(list.files(path="./Rhaebo/Bio_PresWC1.4/", pattern = "asc", full.names = T))
```

but when I run it, it throws me the following message:

```
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.
```

I have the following packages loaded:

```
library(ecospat)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(maptools)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(dismo)
library(ENMeval)
library(rJava)
library(SSDM)
library(usdm)
library(sdm)
library(plyr)
library(rgdal)
library(MigClim)
library(spatialEco)
library(biomod2)
library(devtools)
library(ENMTools)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(terra)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstatsplot)
library(rasterVis)
library(sf)
```

Does anyone know what could cause this problem?

Comment: I don't know half the packages you loaded (some are loded twice, btw!) but if you suspect a conflict between packages, you can always call a function directly from the package you intend to use: `utils::stack(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You should inspect (and show) what is returned by `list.files`. Probably some file that is not a raster.

You should use `pattern = "\\.asc$"` as your pattern. `\\.` is for the dot, `.` is a wildcard. `$` means "ends on"

```
ff <- list.files(path="./Rhaebo/Bio_PresWC1.4/", pattern = "\\.asc$", full.names = TRUE))
ff
s <- raster::stack(ff)
```

Or

```
x <- terra::rast(ff)
```

It is a bad idea (very inefficient) to use ascii files. See `raster::getData` for better access to the old WorldClim data that you are using and `geodata::worldclim` for the current version.

Also, to help you understand what is going on, the first thing I would do is to only load the package you actually need for this line of code (i.e., the raster package) --- and generally, avoid loading packages that are not used in your script. If all these packages are used in your script, then your script is surely too long and complicated and you should cut it into smaller pieces.